# Using Web Services in SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)

Tags: sql-server, web-services, ssis

hello guys can any one tell me the Real Time Usage of a Web Service?

After calling a web service using the **Web Service Task** in **SSIS**, how can we use that web service?

Answer (score 0):

The web service could provide data you are bringing into your database (a stream for import), or it could provide a complex calculation (shipping costs), or it could provide parameter information (today's exchange rate).

Can you give more information about what your usage scenario is?

Comment: Thanks for the Reply .I am new to .NET Technology as well as SSIS too.

i am wondering after calling a webservice using webservice task in SSIS ,the data related to that webservice is going to be stored in database ...Then we use this data to show in the front end isn't?

Please tell me is this the way we use the webservice?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow - you can use a web service for many different types of things, it all depends on the nature of the service.

Comment: No Problem Thanks for the Reply if i have anything i will let you know